# Como comparar string em arquivo de texto com imput do usuário e fazer validação?

Tags: c, arquivo, validação

No finalzinho desse código, eu estou tentando ler os nomes de algumas paises e comparar com entrada do usuário, mas não estou conseguindo obter resultado. Ele continua repetindo. Se ele achar, o programa tem que seguir o fluxo normalmente.

```
void cadastrarDadosAvioes(Aviao *aviao, int *contaAviao, FILE *arquivo, int *baseInicial){
    int opcao=0, i, j, flag=1;
    char nomeAux[MAX], *result;
    strcpy(nomeAux, "");

    FILE *paises;

    //acrescenta dodos ao final ou faz leitura/escrita de arquivo
    arquivo = fopen("cadastroAvioes.txt", "ab");

    //arquivo dos paises

    paises = fopen("paises.txt", "r");

    if(arquivo=NULL){
        printf("\nNao foi possivel abrir o arquivo!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else{    
        do{

            if(*contaAviao==10){
                *baseInicial = (*contaAviao)*2;
                aviao = (Aviao*)realloc(aviao, (*baseInicial)*sizeof(Aviao));
            }

            for(i=0;i<*baseInicial;i++){
                if(stricmp((aviao+i)->codigoIdentificacao, "")==0){
                    do{
                        strcpy((aviao+i)->codigoIdentificacao, leValidaCodigoAviao("DIGITE O CODIGO DO AVIAO:", "\nCODIGO DIGITADO INVALIDO!\n"));
                        for(j=0;j<*baseInicial;j++){
                            if(stricmp((aviao+i)->codigoIdentificacao, (aviao+j)->codigoIdentificacao)==0&&i!=j){
                                flag=0;
                                printf("\nCodigo ja existe!\n");
                            }else{
                                flag=1;
                            }
                        }

                    }while(!flag);

                    do{
                        strcpy((aviao+i)->modeloAviao, leValidaTexto("DIGITE O MODELO DO AVIAO:", "\nMODELO NAO PODE SER VAZIO!\n"));
                        for(j=0;j<*baseInicial;j++){
                            if(stricmp((aviao+i)->modeloAviao, (aviao+j)->modeloAviao)==0&&i!=j){
                                flag=0;
                                printf("\nEsse modelo já existe!\n");
                            }else{
                                flag=1;
                            }
                        }

                    }while(!flag);

                    leValidaCapacidade("INFORME A CAPACIDADE DO AVIAO:", "\nCAPACIDADE INVALIDA!\n", &(aviao+i)->capacidade);

                    do{
                        strcpy((aviao+i)->nomeCliente, leValidaTexto("DIGITE O NOME DO CLIENTE:", "\nNOME INVALIDO!\n"));
                        for(j=0;j<*baseInicial;j++){
                            if(stricmp((aviao+i)->nomeCliente, (aviao+j)->nomeCliente)==0&&i!=j){
                                flag=0;
                                printf("\nEsse nome já existe!\n");
                            }else{
                                flag=1;
                            }
                        }

                    }while(!flag);
                    /*
                    strcpy((aviao+i)->nomePais, leValidaTexto("DIGITE O NOME DO PAIS:", "\nPAIS INVALIDO!\n"));
                    paises = fopen("paises.txt", "r");
                    if(paises=NULL){
                        printf("\nArquivo não existe!\n");
                        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                    }else{
                        //Aqui estou tentando ler o arquio paises.txt

                        while(fscanf(arquivo, "%s", &nomeAux)){
                            printf("%s\n", nomeAux);
                        }
                    }
                    */

                    do{
                        strcpy((aviao+i)->nomePais, leValidaTexto("DIGITE O NOME DO PAIS:", "\nPAIS INVALIDO!\n"));
                        if(!paises){
                            printf("\nArquivo não existe!\n");
                            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }else{
                            while(fscanf(paises, "%s", &nomeAux)!=EOF){
                                if(strcmp((aviao+i)->nomePais, nomeAux)==0){
                                    flag=1;
                                    break;
                                }else{
                                    flag=0;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }while(!flag);

                    break;
                }
            }

            //atualiza contador
            *contaAviao+=1;

            printf("(1)- CADASTRAR OUTRO AVIAO\n");
            printf("(2)- RETORNAR AO MENU\n\n");
            scanf("%d", &opcao);

            if(opcao == 2){
                getch();
                return;
            }

        }while(opcao==1&&(*contaAviao<*baseInicial));
        fclose(arquivo);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Aqui: fscanf(paises, "%s", &nomeAux) não tem este & pois nomeAux já é um endereço. O endereço do início da string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que você está se referindo a isso aqui:

```
while(fscanf(paises, "%s", &nomeAux)!=EOF){
    if(strcmp((aviao+i)->nomePais, nomeAux)==0){
        flag=1;
        break;
    }else{
        flag=0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Você não descreveu o formato do arquivo. Mas acredito que seja um nome de país por linha.
Nesse caso melhor usar a `fgets()` que lê linha a linha:

```
while (fgets(nomeAux, MAX, paises)) {
```

Veja que a `fgets()` pode incluir o caractere de fim de linha (`\n`) na string retornada. Você terá que procurar o caractere e remover.

A `fscanf()` lê até o primeiro espaço em branco, então uma linha com `Estados Unidos` retorna duas vezes: uma para `Estados` e outra para `Unidos`.

Comment: Obrigado, cara! É um arquivo de texto. Eu estava tendo dificuldade com fgets, por isso acabei recorrendo ao fscanf. E, sim, é um nome de país por linha. O meu problema é que eu quero utilizar o resultado da comparação como uma flag. Como você deve ter percebido, o meu programa é todo baseado nisso.

Comment: Perguntinha: Vamos supôr que eu esteja populando um vetor de structs e eu queira, a cada coisa cadastrada, gravar no arquivo (os dados já validados no vetor). Faz sentido o que estou querendo fazer ou há uma forma mais fácil e melhor?

Comment: Não sei se entendi exatamente o que você pretende. Sugiro postar uma nova pergunta e incluir mais detalhes.